# How to move cells down its column based off blank cell row in range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to move cell values in columns K to L down within its column to the same row as every blank cell in column E. [image: every cell value starting in K13:L13 needs to move down range(K13:L) based off the row number of every blank cell in column E]

Hopefully this makes sense but I think i need to figure out how to find each blank cell's row number and force it as a row variable i can then use to tell my code to move cell values in range K13:L. For example, if there's a value in K13:L14 and the blank cells in column E is E20 and E23, i want K13 and L13 to move to K20 and L20 while K14 and L14 move to K23 and L23.

The number of blank cells will always match however many cells with value are in column K/L

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Use the macro below to start your studies.  But first you need to remove the values in column K&L to N&O. (Maybe you can record a macro and add the recorded codes to the start of the codes below.)

```
Sub move_it() 
i = 13 
j = 13

Do While Cells(j, 14).Value <> ""
    
    If Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Range("n" & j, "o" & j).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range("K" & i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    End If 
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that was i needed to offset my copy paste by the rows i needed to move it to!

```
ws.Range("E" & openitemstartrow + 1, ws.Range("F" & openitemstartrow + 
10).End(xlUp)).Copy
targetws.Range("G" & rows.Count, "H" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```